# Value of type string() cannot be converted to string

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting this error, I tried all I could but it still says "Value type of String() cannot be converted to string."

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub
Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()

    RAN = New Random
    WB = New WebClient


End Sub

Private Const IDNum As String = "https://example.com/Data.php"

Private WB As WebClient
Private RAN As Random

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim Account As String() = WB.DownloadString(IDNum).Split(Environment.NewLine)
    AccSplit(Account(RAN.Next(1, Account.Length)))

End Sub


Private Sub AccSplit(ByVal Account As String)

    TextBox2.Text = Account.Split()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Split` here:

```
TextBox2.Text = Account.Split()
```

You are getting a `String` array back.  Calling `Split` with no arguments will split the `String` on whitespace characters.  For instance, this:

```
Dim arr = "Hello World".Split()
```

is equivalent to this:

```
Dim arr = {"Hello", "World"}
```

The `Text` property of a `TextBox` is type `String`, so you can't assign a `String` array to it.  That doesn't make sense.  If you want to fry an egg, do you put am egg carton in the pan?  The correct course of action depends on what you're actually trying to achieve.  If you just want that `String` displayed in the `TextBox` then do this:

```
TextBox2.Text = Account
```

You could also do this:

```
TextBox2.Lines = Account.Split()
```

to display the array with the elements on separate lines in the `TexTbox`, which assumes that you have set its `Multiline` property to `True`.

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox2.Text` is a string. The `string.Split()` function returns an *array* of strings (shown by Visual Studio as a `string()`). Those types don't match up. You can't just assign an array to a string. I might ask if you wanted this:

```
TextBox2.Text = String.Join(",", Account.Split())
```

That will at least compile. But it makes no sense... why split a string, just to join it back again?

Comment: i have a large text.php, and when i click a button it doesn't show it line by line. It shows the whole text. Thats why i am trying to see if splitting will work.