# Can't convert String() to String - Vb Error

Tags: vb.net

I keep getting this error, that can't convert string() to string in vb and i have no idea what i am doing wrong. I am trying to generate id's from the url line by line each time the button is clicked.
Heres the code:

```
    Imports System.Net
    Imports System.IO

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim source As String

    source = New WebClient().DownloadString("https://example.com/Id.php").Split(Enviroment.NewLine)
    TextBox1.Text = source(New Random().Next(0, source.Length))
End Sub
```

Comment: `Split` returns you an array of `String`. You are trying to cram that into a single `String`. `source` should be declared as an array

Comment: [Basically the same issue as a few hours ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45725431/1070452)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Value of type string() cannot be converted to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45725431/value-of-type-string-cannot-be-converted-to-string)

Comment: You really should read a tutorial about arrays. Here some [first](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/) [second](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_arrays.htm)

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Note also that for anything to act as an ID it usually needs to be unique, rather than random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your `source` variable as a String array. As stated by many people already, `Split` returns an array. So if it returns an array you need to make sure the variable your are assigning it to is an array otherwise as you have already seen an error will occur. The below code will fix the issue:

```
Dim source As String()
```

Comment: Thanks! that fixed it :))